# a page can have only one server-side form tag

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

I am using master page and when I run this page, it shows the following error message:

> a page can have only one server-side form tag

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: It's an intrinsic part of ASP.NET web forms that only one server side form tag can be used on a rendered page. You can have other forms, they just can't have the `runat="server"` attribute on them, IIRC.

Comment: Completely remove the tags from the masterpage

Comment: @RussCam Good pattern is ***form tag*** in _Master_ or in _Nested contentPage_ ?

Comment: @Kiquenet good pattern is to no longer use Webforms, but a framework that better fits the paradigm such as MVC :) Having it in the Master page or Content page is going to to depend on whether there are controls in the Master that need to be inside of the form.

Answer (score 29):

I think you did like this:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MasterContent" runat="server">
  <form id="form1" runat="server">

 </form>
</asp:Content>
```

The form tag isn't needed. because you already have the same tag in the master page.

So you just remove that and it should be working.

Comment: your master page have one form already. nested forms are not allowed

Comment: Good pattern is ***form tag*** in _Master_ or in _Nested contentPage_ ?

Answer (score 11):

It sounds like you have a form tag in a Master Page and in the Page that is throwing the error.

You can have only one.

Answer (score 5):

Use only one server side form tag.

Check your Master page for `<form runat="server">` - there should be only one.

Why do you need more than one?

Comment: this page contain only contantplace holder i created new page and running this page after that this show error.

Comment: @Manoj Wadhwani - Make sure both pages have only one server side form tag.

Answer (score 5):

Does your page contain these

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1"
Runat="Server">
</asp:content>
```

tags, and are all your controls inside these? You should only have the Form
tags in the MasterPage.

---

Here are some of my
understanding and suggestion:

Html  element can be put in the body of html pages and html page does
support multiple  elements, however they can not be nested each
other, you can find the detailed description from the W3C html
specification:

## The FORM element

http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html3/forms.html

And as for ASP.NET web form page, it is based on a single server-side form
element which contains all the controls inside it, so generally we do not
recommend that we put multiple  elements. However, this is still
supported in ASP.NET page(master page) and I think the problem in your
master page should be caused by the unsupported nested  element, and
multiple  in the same level should be ok. e.g:

In addition, if what you want to do through multiple forms is just make our
page posting to multiple pages, I think you can consider using the new
feature for cross-page posting in ASP.NET 2.0. This can help us use button
controls to postback to different pages without having multpile forms on
the page:

## Cross-Page Posting in ASP.NET Web Pages

http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/lib...39(VS.80).aspx

http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/lib...40(VS.80).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Sometime when you render the current page as shown in below code will generate the same error

```
StringWriter str_wrt = new StringWriter();
HtmlTextWriter html_wrt = new HtmlTextWriter(str_wrt);
Page.RenderControl(html_wrt);
String HTML = str_wrt.ToString();
```

so how can we sort it?

Comment: this is my exact problem did you find anything to fix this?

Comment: This is the issue here also.

Answer (score 1):

please remove " runat="server" " from "form" tag then it will definetly works.

Answer (score 0):

If you render the page then you need to call `Response.End()` to prevent rendering the whole page.