# A page can have only one server-side Form tag in ASP.net

Tags: .net, asp.net

I'm new to ASP.net and I'm trying to run the following ASP.net code, but it's giving me an error : **A page can have only one server-side Form tag** .

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="FirstWebsite._Default" %>


<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
   <form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:Label runat="server" id="HelloWorldLabel"></asp:Label>
    <br /><br />
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" id="TextInput" /> 
    <asp:Button runat="server" id="GreetButton" text="Say Hello!" />
</div>
</form>
</asp:Content>
```

Could anyone please tell me what's wrong I'm doing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [a page can have only one server-side form tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2910771/a-page-can-have-only-one-server-side-form-tag)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your Masterpage probably has a Form tag as well.

If you want to do multiple Form tags, remove the `runat="server"` attribute and use plain HTML input tags instead.

Answer (score 2):

You are using the master page and the master page would have the form tag. So remove it from this page.

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="FirstWebsite._Default" %>


<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
<div>
    <asp:Label runat="server" id="HelloWorldLabel"></asp:Label>
    <br /><br />
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" id="TextInput" /> 
    <asp:Button runat="server" id="GreetButton" text="Say Hello!" />
</div>
</asp:Content>
```