# Adding form on page in ASP .Net

Tags: asp.net, webforms

Im new in Asp. I've created a new C# simple web site.
it contain navigation menu and 2 pages.
Navigation menu is something like:

```
 <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Default.aspx" Text="Home"/>
```

And all master page is in form which handle menu issues.
Now i'm adding a new web form which contain

```
<form runat="server">
```

And when i try to open this page on server it writes to me:

```
A page can have only one server-side Form tag.
```

How should solve this? should use common form tag?!?

Comment: possible duplicate of [a page can have only one server-side form tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2910771/a-page-can-have-only-one-server-side-form-tag)

Comment: remove the form from your master page

Answer (score 1):

By default ASP.NET pages already have a `<form>` tag that wraps the entire page. So if you add a further `<form>` tag you end up with nested forms which isn't allowed.

You can usually get away with dropping your inner `<form>` tag.

Comment: yes, i removed inner. it is awful solution. now i have a super mega form for entire site..

Comment: @deeptowncitizen Yes, it's a known problem with Web Forms. Things like Razor have pretty much eliminated it now thankfully.

Answer (score 1):

That is because ASP.Net uses only one form to handle everything. You can implement all the functionality using only one form - that is the approach of ASP.Net

You can read a small but nice article at [W3 Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/aspnet_forms.asp)