# A page can have only one server-side Form tag. form error in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

In the below coding,Here i show you my master page & menu user control(Menu user control added to master page).In here it shows the error,

Error generating when i wrap my Usercontrol around runat="server"

> A page can have only one server-side Form tag.

My Master Page

```
<head runat="server">
 <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>

<body>
<uc1:Menu runat="server" ID="Menu" />

<div>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>

</body>
```

My UserControl

```
<form id="text" runat="server">
<asp:LinkButton ID="link_logout" Text="Logout" OnClick="link_logout_Click" runat="server" />
</form>

<%} %>
```

Comment: It's because A page can have only one server-side Form tag. You have 2 as ASP.NET adds one when rendering the master page. So you can't have the form tag in your usercontrol AFAIK

Comment: Apparently you can have multiple form tags, but with hacks... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7544454/can-we-use-multiple-forms-in-a-web-page

Comment: @geedubb when i remove runat="server" from the user control it shows this error >> Control 'Menu_link_logout' of type 'LinkButton' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server.

Comment: can you check your post as it has `<%} %>` at the end - is that intentional?

Comment: @geedubb that is serversideone uses from client side

Comment: Possible duplicate of [a page can have only one server-side form tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2910771/a-page-can-have-only-one-server-side-form-tag)

Answer (score 6):

You should add the `form` to your masterpage like this:

```
<head runat="server">
 <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>

<body>
  <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <uc1:Menu runat="server" ID="Menu" />
    <div>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>
  </form>
</body>
```

Your Usercontrol should look like this (no need for `form` tag):

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="link_logout" Text="Logout" OnClick="link_logout_Click" runat="server" />
```

Comment: Does your code for the content page have a form tag in it? Please update your question with details of the content page

Answer (score -1):

Only one form element is allowed in a page even if we are using a combination of master page and content page. You can remove tag from the child page since already your master page contains the form tag and it will work .