# Two Server Side Form Tag With Two "Update panel" In Asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have server side form tag in one page for login and signup (popup pages) and I want to do login or signup events with ajax process. but I don't add 2nd form tags.
Can I solve this problem? have you any solution! imagine .......`.

When I add second form tag this problem show.' Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: "System.Web.HttpException: A page can have only one server-side Form tag."'

Source Error:

> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Comment: You cannot use multiple form tags on a webforms page (as the error indicates).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [a page can have only one server-side form tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2910771/a-page-can-have-only-one-server-side-form-tag)

Answer (score 0):

WebForm page can have only one server-side Form tag, But you can include multiple HTML form without setting `runat="server"` attribute in HTML form tag.

Below HTML structure can help you achieve what you need, `DefaultButton` attribute in Panel tag can help for simulating submit button for each HTML form tag.

```
<form id="mainForm" runat="server" defaultbutton="Button3">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>

    <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" DefaultButton="Button1">
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <form id="form1">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button 1" UseSubmitBehavior="false" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
                </form>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </asp:Panel>
    <br />
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server" DefaultButton="Button2">
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <form id="form2">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Button 2" UseSubmitBehavior="false" OnClick="Button2_Click" />
                </form>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </asp:Panel>
```